# Remove / add class when based on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a column that slides to the left on a `click` function. I then add the class of `w` to the container to change its width once the column slides out. What I am trying to do is add the class of `e` when it slides back in and then remove the class of `w` by wrapping it in the `toggle` functions, but the container still contains the class of `w` and won't add the class of `e`. Thoughts?

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/QDUQk/1926/

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
}

.container.e {
  width: 80%;
}

.container.w {
  width: 100%;
}

<div class="togl">Menu</div>
<div class="col">
  SLIDE ME SLIDE ME PLX PLX
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>

$('.togl').click(function() {
  if ($('.container').is(':visible')) {
    $('.col').toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'left'
    }, 1000, function() {
      $('.container').addClass('w');
      $('.container').removeClass('e');
    });
  } else {
    $('.col').toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'left'
    }, 1000, function() {
      $(".container").removeClass('w');
      $(".container").addClass('e')
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visibility of `.container` does not change from `true`. Check for `"w"` `className` at `.is()`

```
$('.togl').click(function() {
  if (!$('.container').is('.w')) {
    $('.col').toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'left'
    }, 1000, function() {
      $('.container').addClass('w');
      $('.container').removeClass('e');
    });
  } else {
    $('.col').toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'left'
    }, 1000, function() {
      $(".container").removeClass('w');
      $(".container").addClass('e')
    });
  }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QDUQk/1927/

Comment: @coding_question See [:visible Selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) _"Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout."_ http://jsfiddle.net/QDUQk/1928/

Comment: consider using `hasClass()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Your container visibility does not change on click. Try following,

```
$('.togl').click(function() {
   if ($('.container').hasClass('e')) {
      $('.col').toggle('slide', {
                      direction: 'left'
      }, 1000, function() {
    $('.container').addClass('w');
    $('.container').removeClass('e');
  });
} else {
$('.col').toggle('slide', {
  direction: 'left'
}, 1000, function() {
  $(".container").removeClass('w');
  $(".container").addClass('e')
});
}});
```